# File created with no permissions or owners

Tags: linux, nfs

So there is a Java application that downloads a file from 3rd party site and saves it inside a NFS share. Once in a while though, the saved file has really weird permissions, owners and other meta data applied. There's not even size info available

Windows tools show that file with a 1974 date and 0 bytes in size, on Linux host I don't see any information apart from those showed.

When I try to stat on a file it says it doesnt exist.

Is there any way I can troubleshoot that? If i delete the file, application will redownload it, but in few days,weeks the issue will come back

> -?????????   ? ?           ?                 ?            ? tmp-Football.xml

Thanks

Comment: unreliable nfs connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a corrupt file, and almost certainly was created by NFS before some kind of transmission error (usually associated with restarting the NFS server or clients unmounting errantly while data is in transit from applications).

If the NFS client fails in any way, it will either keep buffered the last bit of information it tried to send and then freeze until the NFS server becomes available again to receive that bit of data, or it will drop the last bit of information and throw an I/O error so that applications may handle that / ignore that (and proceed normally without being frozen).

This is the essential difference between hard and soft mounts. Hard being the freezy type, and soft being the kind that silently corrupt your data when you have the inevitable minor network failure.

Use hard mounts if you are overly concerned with the data integrity of your in-flight data. Use soft mounts if your care more about application stability. If you're having issues with corruption, and you haven't been wildly restarting the NFS server like some datacenter hooligan, then it's a good time to check the NFS server logs and client logs respectively. At the same time, some network diagnostics and monitoring / logs are in order to see if the network is the issue.

Wireshark is great for in-flight traffic monitoring, and has many a GUI to interpret its output in a less horrible way than only plain text, in addition to switch logs. System logs on both systems should reveal most things, as filesystems that become unmounted and servers that get restarted show up pretty well.